# How to solve Streamlit ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000):Max retries exceeded with url: /predict_video?

Tags: python, python-requests, video-streaming, fastapi, streamlit

I was trying to do video streaming on Streamlit ,fetching prediction from FastAPI but got following error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict_video (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1304f85e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

I created fast.py for FastAPI and app.py for Streamlit.

fast.py works just fine when I run localhost:8000/docs to get prediction.

**fast.py**

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Allows all origins
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Allows all methods
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Allows all headers
)


local_model = 'body_5-poses_.pkl'
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic

@app.post("/predict_video")
async def predict_v(file:UploadFile = File(...)):

    contents = await file.read()

    with open(file.filename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(contents)

    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(file.filename)
    _, frame = vid.read()

    with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:

        results = holistic.process(frame)

        pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
        pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

        x_pred = pd.DataFrame(pose_row)
        x_pred = x_pred.T.to_numpy()

        model = pickle.load(open(local_model,"rb"))
        y_pred = model.predict(x_pred[0].reshape(1,132))

    return {'workout pose':y_pred[0]}
```

**app.py**

```
video_file_buffer = st.file_uploader('Choose a file', accept_multiple_files=True)

if video_file_buffer:
    video_bytes = video_file_buffer[0]

    request_url = f"{local_url}/predict_video"
    with st.spinner('Wait for it...'):
        pose = requests.post(request_url, files={'file':video_bytes}).json().get('workout pose')
        if pose:
            st.write(f'Your workout pose is: {pose}.')
        else:
            st.write('Please try again.')
```

Please help me. Thank you !!

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` might not be the same interface - one can be the ipv6 interface, while the other can't. Make sure you use the same in both locations. Try to run the request manually from a Python REPL (the Python console) to see if you get the expected results there.

Comment: I changed the local_url to http://localhost:8000 in app.py, ran it in a python console but still got  HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict_video (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x12e234430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Comment: And you're actually keeping `fast.py` running while you run `app.py`? What does `import requests`, `requests.get('http://localhost:8000')` in a python console say while you have `fast.py` running?

Comment: I get it! I open two terminal windows, keep fast.py running(make run_api) in one shell, meanwhile running app.py(make streamlit) in the other. And then I get my prediction displayed in my Streamlit . Thank you ~

Comment: Correct - if you're not running `fast.py`, `app.py` has no server to query.